# Where can one learn the grammatical functions of the te'amim

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation

I can chant the melodies of the te'amim but I'm having a hard time learning their grammatical functions and structure. Many websites that talk about the te'amim are quick to jump into the ideas of "generals/kings" and "conjunctives/disjunctives" without really explaining what they mean, or move through the information too quickly. Is anyone here familiar with any easy to follow English resources on this topic, or can they answer here in English regarding the grammatical functions?

Comment: Just last week I asked our cantor a similar question -- I want to move beyond knowing how the phrases work to knowing more about how the whole fits together.  We're going to work on this (haven't started yet) -- and Jacobson was the book that came off the shelf.  I look forward to learning more.

Comment: Have you looked into William Wickes' classic treatises?

Comment: Are you looking for all 24 or just the 21 prose (I'm guessing it's the latter and it may be better to ask about the other 3 separately if you are so interested)?

Comment: @DoubleAA It can be the 21 with the 3 separate, or all of them, whatever makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most comprehensive source today on cantillation appears to be the *[Two Treatises on the Accentuation of the Old Testament](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0870680048)* by the 19th Century Hebraist, Dr. William Wickes. (He wrote two treatises because there are two systems of cantillation in the Hebrew Scriptures: one for the 21 books, and one for the other remaining three books of Psalms, Proverbs, and Job, which were sung.) The value of the cantillation was not restricted to melody. Its value also included its logical parsing of phrases into hierarchical chunks. These chunks gave the reader (and listener) the means by which to not only enjoy the Scripture through melody, but also the means to memorize the Scripture (because the melody aligned to the logical hierarchy of chunks of words and phrases, and therefore facilitated memorization).

In this regard, the following paragraphs and illustrations provide a **brief but simplified overview** of the cantillations and their significance.

To begin, the following verse provides an excellent illustration.

First the English -

> **[Micah 7:9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1807.htm#9)** (Mechon-Mamre)
> <sup>9</sup> I will bear the indignation of the LORD, because I have sinned against Him; until He plead my cause, and execute judgment for me; He will bring me forth to the light, and I shall behold His righteousness.

This verse seems typical, but when seen through the “logic” of the cantillation, the meaning of this verse becomes more powerful. For example, this is how this verse appears in the Masoretic Text with its cantillation:

[image]

Below appears the same verse parsed into chunks, based on the hierarchical levels of the cantillation. Please note that the more powerful disjunctive cantillation marks interrupt (and therefore overrule) the less powerful cantillation marks which precede. In essence, each successive phrase is modifying its previous phrase(s) if and when the more powerful disjunctives appear. Since the Athnach is the second most powerful disjunctive, its common appearance is mid-verse, and therefore splits the verse in half; in this regard, there are two parts, which Wickes describes as the dichotomy of Hebrew verse.

Please click to enlarge.

[image]

Please note that the first phrase of words (or first chunk) ends on the Pashta disjunctive accent. The next phrase of words (or chunk) ends on the Zaqef Qaton disjunctive accent, which we note is *more powerful* than the Pashta. Therefore the phrase contained in the Zaqef Qaton chunk subsumes, and therefore modifies the phrase contained by the Pashta. If we continue this process of logic, the schematic arrangement of the verse would look like the following in English.

1. `The indignation of the LORD` **is modified by** `I will bear`
2. `because I have sinned` **is modified by** `against him`

> The Athnach now appears here at the end of phrase #2 on the phrase `against him` (and therefore the first half of the verse has ended). Since the first half of the verse has ended, we can “hear” and therefore understand that phrase #2 modifies phrase #1.

The second half of the verse continues as follows . . .

3. `until He plead my cause` **is modified by** `and execute judgment for me`
4. `He will bring me forth to the light` **is modified by** `and I shall behold His righteousness`
5. `and I shall behold` **is modified by** `His righteousness`

> The Silluq / Sof Pasuq now appears at the end of phrase #5 on the phrase `his righteousness` (and therefore the second half of the verse has ended).
>
> Based on the “logic” of the hierarchy of Hebrew cantillation . . .
>
> - Phrase #5 modifies phrase #4
> - Phrase #5 and phrase #4 modify phrase #3
> - Phrase #5 and phrase #4 and phrase #3 modify phrase #2 and phrase #1

In summary, the cantillation provides nuance and therefore context in which we can better understand the Hebrew Scriptures. In the example above, the cantillation helps us to detect the nuance of this verse. That is, without cantillation, the emphasis might appear to be condemnation with the hopeful expectation of redemption; but when we look at this verse through the lens of cantillation “logic,” then the emphasis of the verse leans more toward the confidence of complete justification.

Comment: i really appreciate the answer. But i was looking for more information, such as, what are disjunctives/conjunctives, are they always paired with certain other symbols? What is the hierarchy, etc. etc. If you can work that into the answer that would go a long way (though i know it would be asking a lot)

Comment: @Aaron - I will refine the answer with more technical info. Your commentary is very constructive, helpful, and much appreciated.

Comment: @Joseph :
Does Dr. Wickes' book include diagrams like the ones you've included here? If so, it would be a most useful resource indeed

Comment: @RIDbarShRu - the book by Dr. Wickes does not include these diagrams, which come from a "modern" source in [Logos Bible Software](https://www.logos.com/product/45606/hebrew-cantillations). In other words, when I combine the research of Dr. Wickes with the diagrams of [Logos Bible Software](https://www.logos.com/product/45606/hebrew-cantillations), the dichotomy described by Dr. Wickes is more clear and understandable.

Comment: @Joseph Thank you for VERY much for this clear and thorough explanation. One piece is ambiguous to me, can you clarify: When you say "Phrase #5 and phrase #4 modify phrase #3" does that mean "phrase #5 modifies phrase #3 and phrase #4 also modifies phrase #3" or "once phrase #5 modifies phrase #4, phrase #5 and phrase #4 become a unit and together modify phrase #3"?
Same question about "Phrase #5 and phrase #4 and phrase #3 modify phrase #2 and phrase #1" dose this mean that the second half of the verse (phrases #5,#4,#3) together modify the first half (phrases #2,#1)?

Answer (score 8):

I have used and found excellent the book [Chanting the Hebrew Bible](https://books.google.com/books/about/Chanting_the_Hebrew_Bible.html?id=gY8JAQAAMAAJ) by Joshua Jacobson.  It comprises a background/history of the subject, a detailed grammatical treatment (one-by-one introducing the disjunctive *te'amim* and their function; introducing the relevant conjunctive *te'amim* with each disjunctive; diagrammatical syntax trees; examples; exercises), a treatment of other reading considerations (including pronunciation, vowels, common issues/mistakes, and rhythm), and concluding with several hundred pages of melodies for accents and their combinations for *Torah*, *Haftarah*, the high holidays, *Esther*, *Eichah*, and the three *megilloth* (although only "standard" Ashkenazi tunes). It comes with a CD of recordings.

There is a cheaper "Student Edition", but I cannot vouch for its contents.  However, you can look [here](https://books.google.com/books/about/Chanting_the_Hebrew_Bible.html?id=cAhkCXAEy6kC&hl=en) for a preview.

Comment: i have seen this book before but did not know if this book was comprised solely from an Ashkenazi perspective in terms of chants and melodies. Can you tell me if this books covers the gamut of Judaism?

Comment: In terms of pronunciation, I recall that it is very inclusive.  In terms of the melodies, I only recall *Ashkenazi* tunes.  However, the grammatical information of the *te'amim*, which is what you requested, does not depend on the melody.

Comment: Thank you. That is what i was needing to know. i will upvote your answer because it points to the right direction, but was hoping to find an online resource

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - I'll check that out! Interested parties might also consider Mordekhai Breuer's *Ta'amei haMiqra* (in Hebrew) and Israel Yeivin's *Introduction to the Tiberian Masorah*. Neither of those present charts or exercises, but Yeivin's is a good reference work on its own.

Comment: Do you still have a copy of this book?

Comment: @Aaron I do not.  I borrowed it from my library.  If you're interested in something particular, I might be able to get it again.

Comment: @magicker72 i'm interested in the pages that have to do with grammar, and conjunctives and disjunctives. i reached out to our synagogue library and they don't have the book. Neither does the Jewish university by us. a Christian seminary has it, but i don't know if they will let me go and make copies of it

Comment: @magicker72 Just letting you know that i found someone who had the book and let me borrow it. It is informative, but the grammar section is still a bit confusing because Sephardim and Ashkenazim have different names for the same te'amim, and so it's difficult to know how to know which one is being discussed. But it is informative and i will revisit my question and the answers here once i have finished looking through this book

Comment: @Aaron Keep [this](http://document.li/N7G4) handy.

Comment: @magicker72 That is veeeery handy. Especially because i had a similar chart but it didn't match the differences as well. This seems to match perfectly. Do you have the original PDF, or is there a way to download it from that page in higher quality?

Comment: @Aaron you can download the PDF from that website, I believe at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good chapter on the te`amim in Israel Yeivin's "Introduction to the Tiberian Masorah". This book draws from ancient Masoretic sources. It is an academic book and is well researched and referenced.

Comment: Is this book available online?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was recently on a similar search and found a great book, which I am enjoying very much. It is called The Glory of Torah Reading by Maurice Gribetz, Dennis Gellis. As far as I can tell it is the only English language book on the subject. Although it is long out of print, copies can be found online and in used bookstores.
[image: Cover of The Glory of Torah Reading]

Answer (score 1):

[The Music of the Hebrew Bible - The Western Ashkenazi Tradition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0954660714) by Victor Tunkel is a very useful book for understanding the grammatical functions of the trop (except for the Ta'amei 'Emes).