# English Book on Trop

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, song-poetry, trop-cantillation

My question is simple: is there an English-language book on cantillation, which includes Ta'amei Eme"t, rare trop, and their grammatical purposes ?

I've seen books on learning to lehn and recognise trop, but generally, these focus entirely on Torah, Neviyim, and Megillot. Since I'm familiar with how to read Torah and haftarot, such a book would be unnecessary in my personal library.

I'm familiar with R' Hirsch's treatment of Ta'amei Eme"t in the back of his commentary on Tehillim, but this doesn't answer all of my questions on the matter.

Comment: It sounds like you need a book that just covers EM"T notes since you say you know the prose-book notes. Why are you asking for a book that "includes" it?

Comment: @DoubleAA, no. I just don't need one which covers trop for the sole purpose of learning to lehn, as in the OP.

Comment: The best resource I've seen on Taamei Emet is http://kinnor.com/Taamei_Emet/, which I from a comment somewhere on this site, I don't remember whose.  One thing it's missing: the tradition that it's based on does not distinguish between conjunctives except in a few limited cases (very odd to my Ashkenazi instincts), so while I have a good sense of the heirarchy of breaks, I don't have a good feeling for which conjunctives go where, as I do in the other 21 sefarim.

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66726/759

Comment: @Heshy It's from https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30702/759

Comment: @noach: Is this helpful? https://books.google.co.il/books/about/A_Treatise_on_the_Accentuation_of_the_Th.html?id=YIZMAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y It’s only on Ta’amei Emet but might be what you’re looking for... (The author has a separate volume on the other 21 books.)

Comment: The introduction to the [Chumash Simanim](http://seforimcenter.com/Chumash-Simanim-with-Tefillot-Shabbat-Ashkenaz---small-size__p-10367.aspx) may interest you. However it is in Hebrew, not English.

Comment: @ezra, Does it cover ta'amei eme"t ?

Comment: If you wanted to understand the structure and grammatical purpose, shouldn't you start with William Wickes? It's on WikiSource.

Comment: Also worth noting i believe only Syrians have a kiving mesorah for how to chant Tehillim.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The Hertz Chumash (at least my version) has the trop with accompanied musical scales/notes.

Comment: @Aaron Moroccan and Yemenite Jews do as well

Comment: @Fei23, the trop in the Hertz Chumash are for the rest of Tana"ch and only show the niggunim (according to the melody used in Minhag Anglia communities). R' Hertz זצ"ל did not discuss their grammatical usage in his Chumash

Answer (score 6):

There are two books written on this by William Wickes.

Here’s the [***Tamei emet version***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1608994422)  and it is even available [online](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonacpoet00wickuoft) [(or here](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/A_Treatise_on_the_Accentuation_of_the_Th.html?id=YIZMAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y)). And here’s the [***the rest of tanach***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1332001394)  version, also [online](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonaccent00wickuoft).

Answer (score 1):

There's [The Music of the Hebrew Bible - The Western Ashkenazi Tradition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0954660714) by Victor Tunkel. 
(although he doesn't talk much about the Ta'amei 'Emes.